# 'Somebody else' over 'Someone else'

Tags: word-usage

[Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=somebody%20else%2Csomeone%20else&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csomebody%20else%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csomeone%20else%3B%2Cc0) shows the usage of 'Someone else' **way** above the phrase 'Somebody else' especially when searched for the results of a past few decades.

Is there any difference? Do we use *somebody* in a special case? Does it sound 'ungrammatical' or 'off' to natives these days?

Comment: Although the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=somebody+else%2Csomeone+else%2Cnobody+else%2Cno+one+else%2C+anyone+else&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15) does show one more heavily favored than the other, it's not like the minority phrasing is [rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=someone+else%2Csomebody+else%2Canise+tea%2C+everybody+else%2C+everyone+else&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15). Good question, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are synonyms. *Someone* may be preferred because it's a syllable shorter ([link](http://grammarist.com/usage/somebody-someone/)), but they mean exactly the same.

Comment: In addition to having the same meaning, both sound perfectly normal in conversational or written American English.  I don't know about British. It seems to come down to whichever the writer prefers: [Find Someone to Love, by Three Dog Night](http://www.metrolyrics.com/find-someone-to-love-lyrics-three-dog-night.html) vs [Somebody to Love, by{?} Jefferson Airplane](http://www.metrolyrics.com/somebody-to-love-lyrics-jefferson-airplane.html)